# Difference May be and May have

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

Which sentence is correct to say?

a) He may be forgot to send an email.

b) He may have forgot to send an email.

c) may be he forgot to send an email.

As per my knowledge sentence a) use to tell current situation.
and sentence b) to tell past completed action which has impact on current situation.

Comment: related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/156838/difference-between-may-have-and-may-be

Answer (score 1):

To me all of them are incorrect.

The (to some extent) correct versions would be:

a) He may **be forgetting** (not *be forgot*) to send an email.

b) He may **have forgotten** (not *have forgot*) to send an email.

c) **Maybe** (= *perhaps*, not *may be*) he forgot to send an email.

The initial b) variant (*have forgot*) is also possible, though not that widespread nowadays (it mostly depends on the variant/dialect of English you use).

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Maulik, the first sentence is incorrect.  When you say that there's a possibility that something is true or will happen, you use the structure may + infinitive without to.  So the right sentence is:

He may forget to send me an email.

As for the second sentence, you use the form "may have" to indicate possibility for recent actions.  So the sentence:

He may have forgot/forgotten to send me an email = Perhaps he has forgotten to send me an email. However, the use of forgot as the past participle is not common in modern English.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think your examples are good advice (for learners): *may have/has forgot*. -- See also: ["Forgotten" or "forgot" as past participle of "forget"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/49484/11482).